# How to reshape a xarray Dataset?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a `xarray.Dataset` named `seisnc_2d` with dimensions `'x': 240200, 'y': 2001` these are 200 seismic shots, each seismic shot has a dimension `(1201,2001)`, which means that the `n` shot will be `seisnc_2d.isel(x=slice((n-1)*1201, n*1201))`.

What I want is to somehow reshape this dataset with a new dimension `shot`, leaving the new `seisnc_2d` dimensions as `'shot':200, 'x': 1201, 'y': 2001` so instead of doing the `x` slice every time I need a seismic shot data, just refer to it as, I guess something like `seisnc_2d.isel(shot=n)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [user guide](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/user-guide/reshaping.html#reshaping-via-coarsen) one can use a combination of [coarsen](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.coarsen.html#xarray.DataArray.coarsen) and [construct](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.rolling.DataArrayCoarsen.construct.html#xarray.core.rolling.DataArrayCoarsen.construct) to reshape the dataset in the desired way:

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.Dataset({"foo": (("x", "y"), np.zeros((240200, 2001)))})
coarse_construct = ds.coarsen(x=1201).construct(x=("shot", "x"))
print(coarse_construct.isel(shot=0))  # => Dimensions:  (x: 1201, y: 2001)
```